# How to use Garamond font in Vietnamese

Tags: pdftex, miktex2.9, mathdesign, garamond

I'm trying to use Garamond font family using `mathdesign` package in a Vietnamese document. My goal is to get the text in the box:

[image]

This is the page 18 of [this document](http://tug.ctan.org/info/Free_Math_Font_Survey/vn/survey-vn.pdf) which is exactly a translation of page 18 of [this document](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf):

[image]

I follow all the instructions I have, especially on the above documents, and get this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
Xin chào Việt Nam $a+b+\sqrt{\pi}$.
\end{document}
```

but it cause an error:

> ```
> ! Font T5/mdugm/m/n/10=ugmr8v at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
>   <to be read again>
>   relax
>   l.3 \babel@aux{vietnamese}{}
> ```

However, still working with `mathdesign`, but `charter` font produces a good output (of course there are some warnings, but it is normal if you use Vietnamese as your document language):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
Xin chào Việt Nam $a+b+\sqrt{\pi}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I got confused - I don't understand why. I made a workaround and do some search but either they don't help me at all or they are a bit too complicated.

I hope you can help me with some ideas.

I'm using Windows 10, MiKTeX 2.9.

I'm sorry if this question is a duplicate. As I said, I read many questions here and more about Garamond but I got nothing `:(`

---

I know I can use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX - it is very easy, but I want to use pdfLaTeX, as my document is very looooong so it would takes centuries to compile using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I get the expected output with TeX Live [picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmhIK.png)

Comment: @egreg On Overleaf it produces a very strange string `Xin chÕào ViòệẤt Nam`. I cannot even compile using MiKTeX. Do you have any idea of the reason of this? I suppose there are some missing but necessary packages, but I don't know which.

Comment: The strange accented characters are an encoding problem. Are you sure you don't have `\usepackage[some option not utf8]{inputenc}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried installing the URW Garamond fonts in MiKTeX without success (some garbled results) due to missing font definitions for Font T5/mdugm/m/it/10=**ugmri8v** at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. with the result most of the Vietnamese text is missing [image]

However whilst testing I found the default EB Garamond seems to be good enough.
For comparison I cannot see any character differences using the source files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After two months, today I just re-research on how to solve this problem, and it appears that I have successfully solved. I post here in case any Vietnamese people also wants to use Garamond in `mathdesign`.

It seems that there is a bug in the MiKTeX tree for fonts like Garamond. I went to [the official VnTeX site](http://vntex.sourceforge.net/) and downloaded the compressed file [`vntex-nonfree-3.2.zip`](http://vntex.sourceforge.net/download/), which contains the fixes.

I extract the file and copy the three folders in it to my MiKTeX tree. In my computer, it is

```
C:\Users\< me >\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9
```

The three available folders `doc`, `fonts` and `tex` will be overwritten and the bugs are fixed.

Then I went to the command line and type

```
initexmf --update-fndb
```

then

```
updmap
```

(more information about these commands: see [here](https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html))

Now I can use Garamond of `mathdesign` in my document!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\begin{document}
Xin chào Việt Nam 123456789
\end{document}
```

[image]

EB Garamond, as suggested by KJO, is great. I just don't really like the numbers of that font :) It is good for novels and articles but not really good for scientific document.

[image]

Comment: If MikTeX has a bug, you can report it here: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md