# How to capitalize the first letter of each word in the title of a bibtex @misc entry in LaTeX tufte-book class

Tags: bibtex, tufte-book

I am using the LaTeX tufte-book class and need to figure out how to capitalize the first letter of each word of the title of the TSEliot bibliography entry in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\title{A Tufte-Style Book\thanks{Thanks to Edward R.~Tufte for his inspiration.}}
\author[The Tufte-LaTeX Developers]{The Tufte-LaTeX\ Developers}
\publisher{Publisher of This Book}

\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath} 
\usepackage{todonotes} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{spreadtab} 
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{epspdfconversion}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}
\usepackage{units}

\providecommand{\XeLaTeX}{X\lower.5ex\hbox{\kern-0.15em\reflectbox{E}}\kern-0.1em\LaTeX}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage{mathdesign}

\newcommand{\openepigraph}[2]{%   
  \begin{fullwidth}
  \sffamily\small
  \begin{doublespace}
  \noindent\allcaps{#1}\\% epigraph
  \noindent\allcaps{#2}% author
  \end{doublespace}
  \end{fullwidth}
}%

\begin{document}

\openepigraph{%
If you came this way,\\\noindent
Taking any route, starting from anywhere,\\\noindent
At any time or at any season,\\\noindent
It would always be the same: you would have to put off\\\noindent
Sense and notion. You are not here to verify,\\\noindent
Instruct yourself, or inform curiosity\\\noindent
Or carry report. You are here to kneel\\\noindent
Where prayer has been valid. And prayer is more\\\noindent
Than an order of words, the conscious occupation\\\noindent
Of the praying mind, or the sound of the voice praying.\\\noindent
And what the dead had no speech for, when living,\\\noindent
They can tell you, being dead: the communication\\\noindent
Of the dead is tongued with fire beyond the language of the living.\\\noindent
Here, the intersection of the timeless moment\\\noindent
Is England and nowhere. Never and always.
}{—T.S. Eliot (lines 41-55)\cite{TSEliot}
}%

\vfill

\openepigraph{%
  The Sky is blue.  
  }
{—Author\cite{Tufte2001}}   
\bibliography{sample-handout} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

Here is the contents of the .bib file:

```
@MISC{TSEliot, 
    author = {Eliot, T. S.}, 
    title = {Four Quartets No. 4: Little Gidding}, 
    month = {December 2013 [Accessed 27 January 2022]},   
    howpublished = {\url{http://www.davidgorman.com/4quartets/4-gidding.htm}}
}

@BOOK{Tufte2001,   
    author = {Edward R. Tufte},  
    title = {The Visual Display of Quantitative Information}, 
    publisher = {Graphics Press},  
    year = {2001},   
    address = {Cheshire, Connecticut},   
    isbn = {0-9613921-4-2}
}
```

Comment: Have you considered changing `title = {Four Quartets No. 4: Little Gidding},` to `title = {{Four Quartets No. 4: Little Gidding}},`?

Comment: Oh, and please don't load the `ucs` package. Really.

Comment: @Mico The double brackets did the trick. Thank you!  Regarding the ucs package, that is my attempt to solve another issue I have which is still unresolved.  Perhaps you would like to take a look?  This is the discussion:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631157/th%c3%adch-nh%e1%ba%a5t-h%e1%ba%a1nh-in-latex-tufte-book-class

Comment: Please see the answer I posted under your earlier query.

Comment: @Mico thanks for following up on my earlier query.  I responded to your recommendation on that thread.